# Test difference of `undef` vs. "empty slot" in array

Tags: arrays, perl, undefined

I have a data structure that features an array with preallocated slots ("empty slots").
Writing a print routine, I wonder how I can make a difference between an "empty slot" and a slot that has `undef` value.
The Perl debugger can do that, but I don't know *how* it detects the difference.

Example:

```
  DB<10> $r = []
  DB<11> $#$r=4
  DB<12> $r->[4]=undef
  DB<13> x $r
0  ARRAY(0x55d8fa6797e8)
   0  empty slot
   1  empty slot
   2  empty slot
   3  empty slot
   4  undef
```

Comment: Note that `$#r = 4;` sets the size of `@r`. You meant `$#{ $r } = 4;`  aka `$#$r = 4;` aka `$r->$#* = 4;`

Comment: Since you didn't actually do `$#$r = 4;`, it brings up the uselessness of the `$#$r = 4;` in your example. `$r->[4] = undef;` will automatically create elements 0..3 if they don't already, as you've demonstrated. In fact, even `$r = [];` is useless in your example, since `$r->[4] = undef;` will autovivify the array and reference.

Comment: There are no "empty slots"  -- once you book memory (either by setting the index of the last elem or by assigning to an elem, per autovivification ) they're undefined ...`undef`.  I don't know what the debugger does

Comment: @zdim, In C terms, the difference is a NULL pointer (`empty slot`) and a pointer to an SV that contains no values (`undef`). In Perl terms, the difference is an element that doesn't exist (`empty slot`) and one that exists but isn't defined (`undef`)

Answer (score 5):

`empty slot` refers to a scalar that doesn't exist (`NULL` pointer, in C terms), while `undef` refers to one that exists but isn't defined (a pointer to a scalar that contains no values).

[`exists`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) can be used to determine if the value an element exists or not. (It will also return true for elements outside of the arrays bounds.)

[`defined`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) can be used to determine if an element is defined or not. (It will also return true for elements outside of the array's bounds and for elements with non-existent values.)

Please don't use exists on array elements. Code relying on identifying whether an elements exists or not will be less readable and less maintainable code than alternatives. The docs say it's not even reliable:

> **WARNING:** Calling exists on array values is strongly discouraged. The notion of deleting or checking the existence of Perl array elements is not conceptually coherent, and can lead to surprising behavior.

---

```perl
use feature qw( say );

sub info {
   my ($a, $i) = @_;
   if ( $i >= @$a          ) { say "$i: Non-existent slot"   }
   if ( !exists($a->[$i])  ) { say "$i: Non-existent scalar" }
   if ( !defined($a->[$i]) ) { say "$i: Undefined"           }
   if ( !$a->[$i]          ) { say "$i: False"               }
   if ( $a->[$i]           ) { say "$i: True"                }
   say "";
}

my @a;
$a[1] = undef;
$a[2] = 0;
$a[3] = 1;

info(\@a, $_) for 4,0..3;
```

Output

```
4: Non-existent slot
4: Non-existent scalar
4: Undefined
4: False

0: Non-existent scalar
0: Undefined
0: False

1: Undefined
1: False

2: False

3: True
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212429/discussion-on-answer-by-ikegami-test-difference-of-undef-vs-empty-slot-in-a).